# Why gethostbyaddr() returning different results?

Tags: php

```
$_POST['url'] = 'fight.com';
$host = gethostbyname($_POST['url']);  //get IP
echo $host . " ";

$ip = gethostbyaddr($host); //get hostname
echo $ip;
```

The expected correct result is:

`50.31.210.85 unknown.servercentral.net`

And indeed it is when I test it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

But when I run this code on my Windows machine I get:

`50.31.210.85 fight.com`

I tested many different domains, is it because of Windows or some other configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host file on your Windows machine or the DNS that your Windows machine is using has record that binds the reverse mapping of `50.31.210.85` to be resolved as `fight.com`

You can very easily test the case with the following 2 commands:

```
nslookup 50.31.210.85
nslookup 50.31.210.85 8.8.8.8
```

The first should return `fight.com` since it will use your machine DNS
The second should return `unknown.servercentral.net` since it will use Google open DNS